# Populate lookup field by clicking search result

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-controller

Im creating custom search result from custom object and facing several problems, I want to populate lookup field based by clicking value that is retrieved by the search function, so there are 2 points here.

1. How to make clickable search result, once the SOSL returned the value, one of the available fields should be clickable
2. After clicking the search result, the lookup field should gets populated with the name and click save should not throw any error

Main VF page

```
<apex:page controller="incDesiredLocationsController" tabStyle="Contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="callAction" action="{!callLookup}"/>
<apex:sectionHeader title="New Desired Location"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="1">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:inputText label="T Lead" style="float:left;" value="{!tleadName}">
<apex:image value="https://api.icons8.com/download/19343120d27c16dd3e9d21ad3aa637f94fd4d5fa/Android_L/PNG/256/Very_Basic/search-256.png" height="20" onclick="callAction()"/>
</apex:inputText>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<center>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
</center>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Lookup page, where the search result T Lead name must be clickable returning to previous page
[image]

```
<apex:page controller="incDesiredLocationsController" tabStyle="Contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="T Lead Lookup"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:inputText value="{!keyword}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}"/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!tleadlist}" var="a">
<apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<center>
<apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!goBack}"/>
</center>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class incDesiredLocationsController {

    String keyword;
    List<TLead__c> tleadlist;
    public String tleadName{get;set;}
    public Id tleadId{get;set;}
    public List<TLead__c> tl {get;set;}


    public PageReference callLookup(){
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/incDLocationsTleadLookup');
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
    }

    public String getkeyword(){
    return null;
    }  

    public List<TLead__c> gettleadList(){
        return tleadlist;
    }

    public void setkeyword(String keyword){
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public PageReference search(){
        List<List<TLead__c>> searchList = [FIND :keyword RETURNING TLead__c(Name, Id)] ;
        tleadList = (TLead__c[])searchList[0];
        return null; 
    } 

    public PageReference goBack(){
    tleadName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(keyword);
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/incDesiredLocationsPage');
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
    if(tleadName == null || tleadName == ''){
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'T Lead is Required!'));
    return null;
    }
        else{
        DesiredLocation__c dLoc = new DesiredLocation__c();
        dLoc.TLead__c = tleadName;
        insert dLoc;

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+dLoc.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working?

Comment: Hi Nick `tleadName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(keyword);` I thought this would get the user input value